# Ruby Watir radio checkbox

Tags: ruby, checkbox, watir

i m trying to set the checkbox on a radio control with the .set? option. it returns false but I'm unable to set the checkbox.

```
<div class="">
<input name="radiostorage" id="zrs" value="2" type="radio">
<label for="zrs">Zone-redundant storage (ZRS)</label>
</div>
```

have tried with label(for: 'zrs').set .click .parent.click .parent.set, also directly trying to click on the input , but nothing happens, any clue on that

TIA

Comment: Any chance you can create an example page? Using `browser.label(for: 'zrs').click` and `browser.radio(id: 'zrs').click` worked for me. I'm guessing there is some CSS/JavaScript that makes a difference.

Comment: I think you are confusing two different types of input controls.   A Checkbox is a single independent thing that can be set or unset regardless of other controls around it.   A Radio control is an analog of the old push-button radios that used to be in cars, where there are a set of selections, but only one can be enabled at once, and enabling one causes any others that were enabled to be disabled.   If you try to address a radio control as a checkbox in watir it's bound to fail, as they are different control types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the way that the radio button is implemented, it will not be considered visible. You will get an exception trying to set it directly:

```
browser.radio(id: 'zrs').set
#=> element located, but timed out after 2 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Radio: located: true; {:id=>"zrs", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"radio"}> to be present (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

Instead of setting it directly, you can click its associated label, which is what an actual user would do:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('https://pricing-calculator.bluekiri.cloud/')
p browser.radio(id: 'zrs').set?
#=> false
browser.label(for: 'zrs').click
p browser.radio(id: 'zrs').set?
#=> true
```

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm , but i m confused as i tried this on the irb and didn t work , shouldn t be any difference doing it from irb or rubymine, anyway , thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
radio = browser.radio(id: 'zrs')
radio.set?        #=> false
radio.set
radio.set?        #=> true
```

See http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Radio

Comment: The `input` element is actually of type "radio", so `checkbox` would need to be `radio`.

Comment: oh yeah, you're right! I was misleaded by mentioning checkbox in the original post.

Comment: I considered editing the original post to reference the proper control type, but decided against it as then it would be very unclear as to his issue.  Also, if he's confused, others are likely as well.   I suspect it is becoming increasingly common for people working with these controls to have never been exposed to the hardware on which the 'radio' control is modeled.  The name for the control likely makes no sense to them.  (if this is you, do an image search for 'push button car radio', it may help your understanding)

Comment: The problem cames locating the element , if i try browser.radio(id: 'zrs') on the irb console i get located false, but if i try with the .set? is shows a false , so i m getting confused at this point because seems i can t find properly the element. Even with the xpath of the radio or the xpath of the input i ve got located false.